# How To Create Website With No HTML In Source Code

Tags: javascript, html, minifiedjs

I've wondered this before, but never gotten an answer. Then just today I came across another site: http://ruralcoz.com/ with no html in the source code. Only a minified script. Does anyone know how the developer built this site, and why they chose to replace all the html with javascript? What's the benefit of this? How is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: That site has **alot** of HTML. You just shouldn't check with rightclick -> show page source, but with your browser's developer tools.

Comment: A valid page that uses only script must have a script element, so it must also be a valid HTML document, which must contain HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [React](https://reactjs.org/) app.  React uses JavaScript to create everything on the page and then loads it into the one root div on the page.

There are advantages to doing it this way and you can read more about it [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/what-and-why-reactjs/)

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. How did you determine it was a React App from the source code?

Comment: @willBeing If you open the dev tools and go to the sources tab you can see in the files that React is referenced and the libraries appear in the node_modules folder.  I also work with React a lot so it just looks familiar at this point.

Answer (score 1):

That site *does* have HTML in the source code, specifically:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Four Points Funding</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.d6132581.css" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
  </head>

  <body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.0673017f.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

All of the above is HTML markup, and pages *must* have HTML to be rendered as HTML pages. There's no way around that.

What this site is lacking is *content in the `<body>`*, which might seem a bit odd, but is very doable. Javascript can be used to create elements and to insert them into the HTML, which is happening here. For example:

```html
<script>
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 'Body content!';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Excuse the title, it could have more accurately stated 'Little' HTML, rather than 'No'. I do realize it has some HTML! But what is the benefit to including the HTML content via Javascript? And how are they building this?